# transiesta convergence for defective graphene

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta, graphene

I have a defective graphene system - 94 atoms (32 in both electrodes and 30 in scattering).
The transiesta run is just not converging. I get this message:

```
SCF_NOT_CONV: SCF did not converge in maximum number of steps (required).
SCF_NOT_CONV: SCF did not converge in maximum number of steps (required).
Geom step, scf iteration, dmax:    0  1000    0.000000
Geom step, scf iteration, dmax:    0  1000    0.000000
Geom step, scf iteration, dq:    0  1000   -4.324581
Geom step, scf iteration, dq:    0  1000   -4.324581
```

Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Sounds like you have too small a device region, see here https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/transiesta-with-siesta-version-4-1-5-not-converging

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transiesta with siesta version 4.1.5 not converging](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/transiesta-with-siesta-version-4-1-5-not-converging)